# Nest.js: Add passport strategy to all routes

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to add passport jwt strategy to all routes that start with `/api`.

I cannot find in the documentation any example of this. I don't want to add the `@UseGuards` decorator in every single endpoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately possible to bind a guard only to a specific route, *however* it would be possible to add in some logic to the guard to check if you are in a specific route (or not) and run logic (or a short circuit). Something maybe like

```
@Injectable()
export class APIGuard implements CanActivate {

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    if (!req.url.contains('api')) {
      return true;
    }
    const isValid = this.checkValidity(context);
    return isValid;
  } 

  private isvalid(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // do your logic. Only brought to a separate method to keep the `canActivate` cleaner
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add to this to add the `APIGuard` in the `useGlobalGuards()` in the `main.ts`

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would be a global guard, but the guarding logic would only work on routes with the string `api` in the url